# Problems with Case and When

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

Ruby beginner here and I'm using Chris Pine's Learn To Program to get started and I solved this orange tree problem, but I decided to tinker with it a bit. In a previous version, I used a bunch of if/else statements for the one_year_passes method, but I wanted to understand how to implement case and when, so I changed it. The problem is, one_year_passes no longer adds oranges when called, it just outputs nil. I'm a little stuck.

```
class OrangeTree

    def initialize
        @age               = 1 
        @height            = 4
        @number_of_oranges = 0

        puts "An orange tree has been planted. It is #{@height} feet tall."
    end

    def height 
        puts "Your tree is is #{@height} feet tall. It has #{@number_of_oranges} oranges."
    end

    def count
        if @number_of_oranges > 0
            puts "There are #{@number_of_oranges} oranges."
        else
            puts "There are no oranges on the tree."    
        end 
    end

    def pick
        if @number_of_oranges > 0
            @number_of_oranges -= 1
            puts 'That was delicious.'
        else
            puts 'Sadly, there are no oranges.'
        end
    end

    def age
        if @age > 1
            puts "The tree is #{@age} years old."
        else
            puts "The tree is one year old."
        end
    end

    def one_year_passes
        @number_of_oranges = 0
        @age += 1
        @height += 2
        case @age
        when @age == 2 || @age == 3 || @age == 4 then @number_of_oranges += 4
        when @age == 5 || @age == 6 || @age == 7 then @number_of_oranges += 8
        when @age == 8 || @age == 9 || @age == 10 then @number_of_oranges += 12
        when@age == 11 then puts 'The orange has given all it has to give and has died'

            exit
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use range:

```
case @age
when 2..4 then @number_of_oranges += 4
when 5..7 then @number_of_oranges += 8
when 8..10 then @number_of_oranges += 12
when 11 then puts 'The orange has given all it has to give and has died'
end
```

`case` statement uses `===` operator and the statement evaluates like this `2..4 === @age` and so on.
See [Range#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

Comment: Or you could write, `if @age == 11; puts 'The orange...died'; else; @number_of_oranges += case @age; when 2..4 then 4; when 5..7 then 8; when 8..10 then 12`; end; end`.